# is there a way to update the background colour with Vanilla JavaScript conditionals?

Tags: javascript, html, css, conditional-statements

I am trying to update the background color of the following items(12 in total) and get it to refresh every 5s depending on what we get from the server, however, it doesn't seem to be working.

this is what I have so far:

```js
let pegInactive = 0;
let pegActive = 1;
let pegFinished = 2;

function createPeg(name, checkActive) {

  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);
  console.log(uiProgressBar);

  let currentStatus = 0;

  // returns the current time
  function getStatus() {
    return currentStatus;
  }

  console.log(uiProgressBar);

  function checkActive(newStatus) {
    if (newStatus < 0) newStatus = 0;

    currentStatus = newStatus;
    console.log(newStatus);
  }
  return {
    ui: {
      progressBar: uiProgressBar,

    }
  }
}
const intervalId = setInterval(updateBackgorund, 5000);

const allPegs = [
  createPeg('peg-1', pegActive["one"]),
  createPeg('peg-2', pegActive["two"]),
  createPeg('peg-3', pegActive["three"]),
  createPeg('peg-4', pegActive["four"]),
  createPeg('peg-5', pegActive["five"]),
  createPeg('peg-6', pegActive["six"]),
  createPeg('peg-7', pegActive["seven"]),
  createPeg('peg-8', pegActive["eight"]),
  createPeg('peg-9', pegActive["nine"]),
  createPeg('peg-10', pegActive["ten"]),
  createPeg('peg-11', pegActive["eleven"]),
  createPeg('peg-12', pegActive["twelve"]),
];

// peg1 === 0 ? peg1BarFill.style.background="green" : peg1BarFill.style.background="red";

function updateBackgorund() {
  for (const peg of allPegs) {
    const backgroundColour = peg.getStatus()
    if (backgroundColour > 0) {
      uiProgressBar.Style.backgroundColour = "green";
      console.log(uiProgressBar.Style.backgroundColour = "green");
      if (backgroundColour === 0) {
        uiProgressBar.Style.backgroundColour = "red";
      } else {
        uiProgressBar.Style.backgroundColour = "gray";
      }
    }
  }
}
if (allPegs.every(peg => peg.getStatus() === 0)) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-white : whitesmoke;
  --color-light-gray : lightgray;
  }
  .peg-wrapper {
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  height: 97px;
}

.peg-1-bar, .peg-2-bar, .peg-3-bar, 
.peg-4-bar, .peg-5-bar, .peg-6-bar, 
.peg-7-bar, .peg-8-bar, .peg-9-bar, 
.peg-10-bar, .peg-11-bar, .peg-12-bar {
  background-color: var(--color-light-gray);
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.peg-1-bar-fill, .peg-2-bar-fill, .peg-3-bar-fill, 
.peg-4-bar-fill, .peg-5-bar-fill, .peg-6-bar-fill, 
.peg-7-bar-fill, .peg-8-bar-fill, .peg-9-bar-fill, 
.peg-10-bar-fill,.peg-11-bar-fill, .peg-12-bar-fill {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="peg-wrapper">
  <div class="peg-name-1" ><h4> 1</h4></div>
  <div class="peg-1-bar" ><div class="peg-1-bar-fill" ></div></div>
</div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-2" ><h4> 2</h4></div><div class="peg-2-bar" ><div class="peg-2-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-3" ><h4> 3</h4></div><div class="peg-3-bar" ><div class="peg-3-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-4" ><h4> 4</h4></div><div class="peg-4-bar" ><div class="peg-4-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-5" ><h4> 5</h4></div><div class="peg-5-bar" ><div class="peg-5-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-6" ><h4> 6</h4></div><div class="peg-6-bar" ><div class="peg-6-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-7" ><h4> 7</h4></div><div class="peg-7-bar" ><div class="peg-7-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-8" ><h4> 8</h4></div><div class="peg-8-bar" ><div class="peg-8-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-9" ><h4> 9</h4></div><div class="peg-9-bar" ><div class="peg-9-bar-fill" ></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-10"><h4>10</h4></div><div class="peg-10-bar"><div class="peg-10-bar-fill"></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-11"><h4>11</h4></div><div class="peg-11-bar"><div class="peg-11-bar-fill"></div></div></div>
<div class="peg-wrapper"><div class="peg-name-12"><h4>12</h4></div><div class="peg-12-bar"><div class="peg-12-bar-fill"></div></div></div>
```

Could anyone give me a hand? I, ve been trying to get it to work for a month and can't get out of this stuck.

I Get the following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: peg.getStatus is not a function
at test4.js:70:30
at Array.every ()
at test4.js:70:13

Uncaught TypeError: peg.getStatus is not a function
at updateBackgorund (test4.js:57:34)
updateBackgorund @ test4.js:57
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ test4.js:36

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. For that we don't need all 12 "peg"-items (and the dependent CSS rules and script repititions...)

Comment: You could try `uiProgressBar.style.backgroundColour` instead of `.uiProgressBar.Style.backgroundColour` :)

Comment: see your HTML, there is problems on `5` `6`, you also have JS errors in console...

Comment: Your JS Code is a mess. Try rewriting it and look out for "Style" - it should be "style". Do you want to change every pegs color every 5s or just a specific one? I feel like you haven't done much with the code and you just want somebody to do it for you. If you have got Error messages then look them up and solve them...

Comment: I am trying to update the front-end every 5s  to reflect what I am getting from the server(back-end). it should be reflected in every area, I am not asking for an answer, just some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the method `getStatus()` in the `peg` object. Maybe the following might help:

```
function createPeg(name, checkActive) {

  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);
  console.log(uiProgressBar);

  console.log(uiProgressBar);

  function checkActive(newStatus) {
    if (newStatus < 0) newStatus = 0;

    currentStatus = newStatus;
    console.log(newStatus);
  }
  return {
    ui: {
      currentStatus: 0,
      progressBar: uiProgressBar,
      getStatus: function() { return this.currentStatus; }
    }
  }
}
```